# Is there a case that random forest data (a bunch of trees) consumes MB or GB of memory?

Tags: random-forest

Is there any case that random forest (a bunch of trees) consumes too much memory in practice?
I'm wondering why my scikit-learn consumes large amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it could consume any amount of memory. 
You could use an infinite amount of trees.